# How to use unicode in string literals

Tags: r, unicode

I know that I can use the `\U` prefix to encode unicode characters:

```r
cat("\U00DF", "\n")
# ß
```

But how would I use it in a longer string?

```r
cat("Stra\U00DFe", "\n")
# Stra෾
```

Do I really need to `paste` strings along the unicode "breaking points"?

```r
cat(paste0("Stra", "\U00DF", "e"), "\n")
# Straße
```

I guess I do not see the wood for the trees, so any hint is highly appreciated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could `{}` of your unicode like this:

```r
cat("Stra\U{00DF}e", "\n")
#> Straße
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-17 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I knew it was something as simple as that. Thanks!

Comment: Was not aware of that. Is there any documentation for this?

Comment: This is mentioned in `?Quotes` as an "alternative form", but the doc doesn't seem to elaborate on the need to use it in specific cases.

Answer (score 4):

Using lowercase:

```
cat("Stra\u00dfe")
# Straße

# without cat
print("Stra\u00dfe")
# [1] "Straße"

"Stra\u00dfe"
# [1] "Straße"
```

Comment: Note though that the issue might arise again if a code shorter than 4 digits is used, e.g. `cat("Stra\u0dfe")` (valid code without first leading 0) will fail (it rightly attempts to interpret the maximal number of following hex digits allowed by this syntax) while `cat("Stra\u{0df}e")` works.

Answer (score 4):

This might also be solved by maxing out the number of digits in the hex code allowed by the `\Unnnnnnnn` syntax (that is, 8), with leading `0`s.

```
cat("Stra\U000000DFe", "\n")
```

will work, resolving the ambiguity (the parser attempts to use the max number of digits allowed by the syntax. This also illustrates the cause of the original unwanted behavior: 5 digits are available, so 5 are interpreted as code. Note that `cat("Stra\U0DFk")` also works, since `k` cannot be interpreted as an hex digit).

Answer (score 1):

Or just `cat` the strings individually with `sep = ""` without `paste`?

But sure the solution by @Quinten is much better.

```
cat("Stra", "\U00DF", "e", "\n", sep = "")

Straße
```